# Right and Left click swap after mouse event

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent

*I'm using windows 7 and VB2010 but i never studied it, i'm an autodidact (i copy some code from the internet and paste it together hoping it works) and i don't even speak english, but hopefully you'll understand what i'm writing.*

I'm trying to create a program that clicks in another window (another process), and it seems to work pretty good. But when the process finish i need to close and restart it.
But here there is a bug: wherever i try to simulate a click (now i'm clicking on the desktop) it doesn't work. Rather when i simulate a left click the desktop menu opens up (the one with the desktop option, like create a new folder, change desktop background, etc) and if i try to click on something, even on my form, nothing will happen (even if I place the mouse over a button, it won't highlight). When i try to simulate a right click nothing happens, too.
The only way to bring it back to normal is to physically right and then left click with the mouse. But i need this to happens without my intervention. Is there any way to fix this?
(it seems to happen sometimes even if you simulate a dozen of random and alternate left and right click on the desktop).
This is my code:

```
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwflags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cbuttons As Integer, ByVal dwextrainfo As Integer)
Private Const mouseclickdown = 2
Private Const mouseclickup = 4
Private Const rightclickdown = 8
Private Const rightclickup = 10


Cursor.Position = New Point(x,y)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)


Cursor.Position = New Point(x,y)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
mouse_event(rightclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
mouse_event(rightclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, but I see a couple potential problems.

First, rightclickup should be 16, not 10. Code snippets you've probably found online typically use hexadecimal for these constants. 16 in hex looks like the number 10.

Second, the mouse_event() declaration in C# actually uses a pointer for the last argument. Instead of passing in a zero, I pass in a new instance of IntPtr. I'm not sure of the VB equivalent at this point; it may not be a real problem.

Try changing that constant, and let me know if it worked for ya.